# Is Xamarin Studio supposed to generate an APK when compiling for debug target?

Tags: apk, xamarin-studio

I don't want to build a release APK. I simply compile my xamarin app, with the Debug target selected, and then I look in my /bin/Debug/ folder and I only see .dll, .dll.mdb, .pdb files, but no .apk file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the .apk set the build to Release mode and go to Project->Create Android Package

Answer (score 2):

In Xamarin version 6.3:

1. Set your project configuration to "Release".
2. Right click on your project -> Archive for Publishing.

[image]

Source:https://developer.xamarin.com/Guides/Android/Deployment,_Testing,_and_Metrics/publishing_an_application/Part_1_-_Preparing_an_Application_for_Release/#Archive_for_Publishing