# How to generate an .apk file from Xamarin.Forms Project using Visual Studio?

Tags: android, visual-studio, apk, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms project that I'd like to distribute as an `apk`; however I cannot find how to generate a `.apk` file in Visual Studio - how would I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195004/is-xamarin-studio-supposed-to-generate-an-apk-when-compiling-for-debug-target

Answer (score 54):

When using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 with the latest Xamarin tools (which is v4.2.2.6 when writing this answer), right click your Android project and select "**Archive...**" as described here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/#Compile

This will open the **Archive Manager** and begins the process of archiving the App bundle. When the archiving is finished, you can click on the button "**Distribute...**" at the right bottom corner of the Archive Manager to create a signed APK. This is described here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/

Note: if you do not use a signed APK, you will probably get a parse error if try to install on an Android device.

Answer (score 28):

Try The Following Steps:

1. You need to change Your Project Mode from debug to release.
2. Rebuild your project.
3. Go to Solution Explorer -> Android project (right click) --> Archive --> Distribute -- AdHoc --> Sign & Add Details --> Save As

The APK is Ready To Publish in Play Store

Answer (score 12):

Firstly your project should be in Release Mode
Then simply Right Click on your android Project and select "Export Android Package (.apk)"

[image]

Your .apk file will be created in your project directory

Comment: i've already done that but i didn't find any file in my project directory .

Comment: does is tell whether the build of the package has finished successfully ? in my case the answer is no.

Comment: Do I need to sign the APK if I wish to distribute the app via the Google Play Store?

Answer (score 5):

You can find your APK or IPA file in your bin folder from your project. So in Android it is located here: `Project.Droid/bin/MyAppName.apk`

This might not be the case when you build with the App Store configuration or maybe there are other problems with the Xamarin IDE. In that case you can do a right click on your project and choose **Archive for Publishing** which will save your artefact here `~/Library/Developer/Xamarin/Archives/`. Alternatively right click on your project and choose **View Archives**

Answer (score 3):

**Steps to Create APK in Visual Studio 2022:**

1. Build app in RELEASE mode.
2. Right Click on Android Project > Properties > Android Options > Uncheck “Use Fast Deployment”, if checked.
3. Right Click on Android Project > Archive.
4. Distribute > AdHoc > Add signing Identity by clicking on "+" icon and fill the details as shown in image below.
5. Save the app and you’re done.

[image]